# Push notifications from firebase in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that uses `cordova-plugin-firebasex` for the push notifications. But they don't appear in notification center while app is in the background. I'm using iOS simulator in XCode.

Can I test Firebase notifications in simulator while app is in the background? Or I need real device for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simulators are not supporting push notifications. You can see this output text from Firebase SDK in yuor console output
Like

> 6.27.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote notifications are not supported in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can actually test the notifications locally using the XCode Simulator Control Utility:

```bash
xcrun simctl push booted payload.json
```

with the following payload stored in the JSON file in your local directory:

```json
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Local notification test",
            "body": "This is the body of your local notification."
        }
    },
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "com.example.example"
}
```

Where the `com.example.example` is your bundle identifier.

For more information have a look at the utility's documentation:

```bash
xcrun simctl push --help
```